# Custom Number Format Ms Access

Tags: ms-access, formatting, format

I've been searching and can't seem to find a solution. How do I have a number displayed like this `1(2016)` in a Ms Access Table. A user enters `102017` and it is displayed as `10(2017)`. The closest I seem to get is `#(#,###)` but I don't want the commas.

Comment: If this really is a date field leave it as a date field and format it in either your form or underlying queries. If it's derived from a date then simply display it as you need it don't try and store it. 
Format(YourDate,"m(yyyy)") should work

Comment: Sorry not mentioning it before. It is not a date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this format: `#(0000)`